# Does big recyclerView dataset lead to low memory exception?

Tags: android, dataset, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerView that use an `ArrayList< ModelClass>` as dataSet:

```
ArrayList<ModelClass> dataSet =  new ArrayList<>();    

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
```

now , when user scroll down new item will add to dataSet and this insertion can happen for infinite time .
My questions are:

1. Will the growth of this database can cause an low memory exception ?
2. if the above question is true , Do use `caching techniques` seem logical?

Comment: it depends on your items. if they have images and you load them without imageloaders it will cause low memory exception

Comment: thank you , i use glide as image loader

Comment: so it will be ok. I didn't encounter any low memory exception on recyclerviews personally